# trying to bind datagrid item source to a property in another class

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a WPF app with a MainWindow. The MainWindow consists of several CLR properties of type ObservableCollection. The MainWindow has a datagrid, whose ItemsSource property is bound to one of the observable collections (works fine). Next, I have a dialog. Its purpose is to display one of the observable collections from the main window in a datagrid. The dialog gets instantiated in the MainWindow. Initially I was passing the ObservableCollection to the dialog's constructor, and copying it into the dialog's CLR property. Then I would set the DataContext of the dialog to itself, and bind the ItemsSource property in the datagrid to the name of the CLR property. This worked fine.

Is there a better way to do this instead of passing the observable collection through the constructor? I tried setting the ItemsSource property of the Datagrid in the dialog to the observable collection in the MainWindow by using the GUI editor, which generated a binding using RelativeAncestor, but the data did not show. The problem is I have a bunch of dialogs that are meant to display data from the MainWindow, and I feel like there should be a simpler solution rather than passing everything to dialog's constructor. Also, would the dialogs be considered SubViews? The main window is a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your `Dialog` control is named `DialogControl` and has a `DependencyProperty` named `Items` defined in its code behind. In the XAML, I would bind this property to the `DataGrid` like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DialogControl}}" />
```

This `RelativeSource` binding will go off and search through the properties of your `DialogControl` class and find the `Items` property. Note: Do NOT set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` to itself.

Now in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file where you instantiate your `DialogControl`, you can set the `Items` property:

```
DialogControl dialogControl = new DialogControl();
dialogControl.Items = someCollection;
dialogControl.Show();
```

UPDATE >>>

Oh I see what you're after now... you want to bind from your `UserControl` to the actual collection in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file. You can still follow my advice, but instead of having the `DependencyProperty` in your `DialogControl`, you need to have it in your `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file. In that case, your binding in the `UserControl` would be:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=
FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}" />
```

For this to work, the `Items` property *must* be a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm kind of doing that already. Instead of setting the Items field, I'm passing it in the constructor. And it is just a standard CLR property, not a dependency property. This works fine, but I was just wondering if there's a way to do this without copying the observable collection to the items property.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that solution. You are an alien?

Comment: Haha... I'm guessing that you're talking about my picture... that's Photoshop.